# Rails 4 - routing actions for contact form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, get, routes

I have two actions in the controller:

```
  def report
    @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  end
  def reportForm
    @user = User.find_by_slug(params[:slug])

    Thread.new do
      mail = ...
    end
    @message = 'Thanks!'
  end
```

and in routes:

```
# User report form
  get "/user/:slug/report", to: "users#report"
 # Catch report form and action
  post "/user/:slug/report", to: 'users#reportForm'
```

And the view:

```
<form method="POST" action="/user/<%= @user.slug %>/reportForm">
...
```

But the problem is, that when I send the form, the action `reportForm` is not called and instead of that is only refresh the current page with the form.

What's wrong here?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Not sure.. But as per the convention your method name is not meeting it.. Change `reportForm` in 3 places(route file and action name and view) to `report_form` and let me know..

Comment: Also _please_ use Rails' form helpers instead of building all the routes and HTML by hand: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms

Comment: @ArupRakshit unfortunately, it didn't help... Still the same. Even if I change the action in the form on `/usasfdsgasdhshs`, it's still the same, the app is redirected back on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

**Form Helpers**

The first thing that's wrong is you're not using the [`form helpers`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) that Rails provides - this is a problem because you'll end up with niggly little problems like the one you're receiving:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   get  :report #-> domain.com/users/:id/report
   post :reportForm #-> domain.com/users/:id/reportForm
end

#view
<%= form_tag user_reportForm_path(@user) do %>
   ...
<% end %>
```

---

**Routes**

The second issue you have is to do with your routes

You've set the following routes:

```
get "/user/:slug/report", to: "users#report"
post "/user/:slug/report", to: 'users#reportForm'
```

This means you've got to send the request to `domain.com/user/user_slug/report`. Your form sends the URL to `reportForm`...

You should see my routes above for the solution to this problem

But more importantly, you should read up on [`nested resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   match :report, action: "reportForm", via: [:get, :post] #-> domain.com/users/:id/report
end
```

---

**Slug**

Finally, you're trying to use `params[:slug]` in your controller

With the resourceful routes you *should* be using in Rails, you'll be passing `params[:id]` most of the time. This should not be an issue (what is contained in `params[:id]` can be anything).

I would highly recommend looking at a gem called [`friendly_id`](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id), which makes including `slugs` in your application a lot simpler:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def reportForm
       User.find params[:id] #-> will use either `id` or `slug`
    end
end
```